# Facebook Register Plugin not showing up?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to implement Facebook Register Plugin on my website for landing pages.

I am following this guide:
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/registration/v2.0

I've written following code:

```
  <div id="registration">
    <iframe src="https://www.facebook.com/plugins/registration?client_id=660604224016242&redirect_uri=http://automaton.in/store_user_data.php?&fields=[{"name":"name"},{"name":"email"},{"name":"password"},{"name":"gender"},{"name":"birthday"}]">
    </iframe>
  </div>
```

But nothing is showing up instead of a box with border.
[image]

I've also created my facebook app with app-id 660604224016242.
Also, I am running my site locally without a local server! Do I need to run this on a server?

Please help me, I really need to implement this plugin!

Comment: You must be using graph api 2.0. This functionality is removed after graph api 1.0 . You can check the warning in top of the document.

Comment: So, How can I use this plugin then?

Comment: If you are using GRAPH API 1.0 only then you can use it else You Can't.

Comment: So, this plugin is deprecated now? Means discontinued???

Comment: Nope this is not deprecated.. This is available for Graph Api 1.0 only.

Comment: So, how to use Graph API 1.0?
And, will it affect users who are using Graph API 2.0?
Sorry, I don't know much about facebook graph API!!